# efficiently grep an interval of a sorted file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, performance

My file has millions of lines, resides in memory `/dev/shm/tmp.file`, is accessed by multiple threads, looks like this

```
831092,25a1bd66f2eec71aa2f0a8bb3d,/path/to/a/file
4324,8d83c29e4d8c71bd66f1bd66fs,/path/to/another/file
...
```

and is sorted by the part after the second `,` with `sort -t , -k3`.
In general each line has the shape `[0-9]*,[0-9a-z]*,.*` and file paths can contain any characters except `\0` or `\n`.

I need to extract the lines of all files that reside within a given directory as quickly as possible and without making an additional copy. Since the file is sorted that way, the lines I am looking for are an uninterrupted chunk of the file.

Currently I use `grep -F ',<directory>' /dev/shm/tmp.file` but I know it would be much quicker to do a binary search for the first hit and then expand the chunk line by line or with another binary search without reading in the entire file for each new line. However, this has to be integrated into a bash script, and I found no way to do something like lseek in the bash.

There is [sgrep](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/jjaakkol/sgrepman.html) but it requires the complete lines to be sorted.

How can I extract all matches with `',<directory>'` quicker than `grep -F`?

**Edit:** The input `/dev/shm/tmp.file` is only there to do this kind of extraction. Hence, pre-processing it in some way to make the job easier is an option.

**Edit:** `a.b` sorting between `a` and `a/b` is not an issue since all subdirectories should be included in the chunk.

Comment: If this was something I did and wanted to be able to do efficiently and often, I would probably put it into a database and index the paths by directory inode and mountpoint, or something.

Comment: This is well beyond the limits of bash.  You could do it a little *faster* using awk, as you could make awk stop once it had found the end of the block of lines.  However it would still search in order.

Comment: Are those records NUL-delimited? If not then I'd expect newline to be another character that can't be found in your file names. You'll also want to make sure that `sort -t , -k3` is done in the C locale. Even in the C locale, note that `a.b` sorts inbetween `a` and `a/b`.

Comment: `zsh` and `ksh93` have builtin seeking operator, but even there, you wouldn't want to implement that with shell builtins. mmapping it would probably make more sense than seeking here anyway.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas You are right `\n` can also be excluded. How would I do the mapping?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you changed `831092,25a1bd66f2eec71aa2f0a8bb3d,/path/to/a/file` to
`/path/to/a/file,831092,25a1bd66f2eec71aa2f0a8bb3d`

You could do it with:

```
look /path/to/ /dev/shm/tmp.file
```

`look` is a traditional Unix utility from the 70s, not specified by POSIX but fairly common. On Debian and derivatives, you'll find one in the `bsdmainutils` package, there's also one in util-linux (also copied from BSD, not on the Debian package by the same name).

`look` `mmap()`s the file and does a binary search.

However note that the Debian implementation reverts to a basic linear search a la `grep` unless you pass the `-b` option (sigh). So, on Debian or derivative, you'll want:

```
look -b /path/to/ /dev/shm/tmp.file
```

Also note that some implementations have a limit on the size of the file they can handle ([see corresponding bug with patch for Debian's](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=893033))

Comment: This is neat, thanks. A downside is that I will have to change the format back again before passing on the chunks.

Comment: The file size is an issue as look reports `look: /dev/shm/tmp.file: File too large`. I am not sure I can get this to work on different Debian/Ubuntu machines. Will look into it tomorrow.

Comment: The sorting of the proposed format for `look` does not always agree with the sorting by file paths. E.g., if there are files `a` and `a,5` in a directory, then sorting for look would probably put `a` before or after `a,5` depending on the number coming after the file name. Also look occasionally complains `look: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character`. Other than that it's a brilliant solution that works flawlessly with Tomaž Šolcs patch. The other patch, however, seems to break look for regular files.

Comment: @katosh, you'll want to use `LC_ALL=C` for both `sort` and `look`. The order is generally not deterministic in other locales  (and is much more complex and expensive)